# Combination to find integers satisfying a condition

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality, integers

> Let $n$ and $k$ be positive integers such that $n\ge\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.
> The number of solutions $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{k})$, with $x_1\ge1$, $x_2\ge2$,..., $x_{k}\ge k$ for all integers satisfying $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{k}=n$ is?

I substituted the last equation in the first inequality.
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{k}\ge\frac{k(k+1)}{2}.$$
Took $x_1$ as $1+ t_1$, $x_2$ as $2+t_2$...where $t_i\ge 0$. On simplifying by using sum of k numbers, I end with with
$t_1+t_2+\dots+t_{k} \ge0$. Since $x_1,x_2$... are in increasing order, and sum of all $t$ values is $0$, I conclude that this is only possible when $t=0$. Therefore only one solution is possible when $LHS = RHS$. The inequality is not valid.

But the answer is $\frac{1}{2}(2n-k^2+k-2)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please check the given answer? In my opinion is the one given in my answer below.

Comment: @RobertZ hey i just saw the answer as my net was down. the answer given is 1/2 (2n-(k^2)+k-2) and the answer you have given doesn't simplify to it. The method given in the book uses the sum of coefficients of t^n in (t + t^2 +t^3 ...)(t^2 + t^3 +....)(t^k + t^(k-1)+...). If this is helpful in answering as i didnt understand what happening here.

Comment: What is the title of the book?

Comment: it is a book of past IIT-JEE questions

Comment: I edited my answer (which is correct). Please take a look at the P.S.

Comment: It’s like partition questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{k}$ is not necessarily increasing, so your conclusion is not correct.

Let $t_k=x_k-k\geq 0$, then we have to count the number of non-negative integer solutions of
$$t_1+t_2+\dots+t_k=n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
which is, by [Stars-and-Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), given by
$$\binom{n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{\frac{2n-k^2+k-2}{2}}{k-1}.$$

P.S. My answer is correct. Probably there is a typo in your book. The integer $\binom{\frac{2n-k^2+k-2}{2}}{k-1}$ is precisely the coefficient of $t^n$ in
$$ (t + t^2 +t^3+ \dots)(t^2 + t^3 +t^4+\dots)\dots (t^k + t^{k+1}+t^{k+2}+\dots),$$
that is
$$[t^n]\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{t^j}{1-t}=[t^{n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}](1-t)^{-k}
=(-1)^{{n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}}\binom{-k}{n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}=\binom{n-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k-1}{k-1}.$$
Numerical example. Take $n=8$ and $k=3$, then it is easy to see that
$$ (t + t^2 +t^3+ \dots)(t^2 + t^3+ t^4 +\dots)(t^3 + t^{4}+t^{5}+\dots)
=t^6+3t^7+6t^8+\dots$$
and the coefficient of $t^8$ is $6$:
$$\binom{\frac{16-9+3-2}{2}}{3-1}=\binom{4}{2}=6.$$

Comment: doesn't this x1≥1, x2≥2,..., xk≥k imply it is increasing ?  x1+x2+⋯+xk=n and n and k both are positive. sum we know xk≥1 as the first lowest number  x1≥1

Comment: No. Take $n=12$ and $k=3$, then $x_1=5\geq 1$, $x_2=4\geq 2$ and $x_3=3\geq 2$ satisfy the given conditions, but they are not increasing.